# how to debug password authentication failed with django postgres and docker-compose

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, docker

How do you solve the problem below

Not sure how i messed up my **postgresql** configuration (**role + password** etc...)

I am using **docker-compose** **django** **postgres13.3**

```
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:23.221 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:23.222 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:23.222 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:23.226 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:23.233 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-07-23 12:59:50 UTC
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:23.252 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:27.817 UTC [34] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:27.817 UTC [34] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
db          |   Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:34.672 UTC [35] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db          | 2021-07-23 13:05:34.672 UTC [35] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
db          |   Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"

...

backend     | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
backend     |     self.connect()
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
backend     |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
backend     |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
backend     |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
backend     |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
backend     |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
backend     | psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

i tried to manually edit the settings .py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': "postgres",
        'USER': "postgres",
        'PASSWORD': "postgres",
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Nothing seem to work with the usual `postgres` user details, i accessed the database `psql postgres`, tried to update the password , create new role, tables and privileges, that work but when i start `docker-compose up -d --build` and check `docker-compose logs` it still not working

this is my second day trying to debut this, please help

Comment: "i went to the database and tried to update the password and privileges and it still not working"  What did you actually do?  Did you get errors when you did it?

Comment: @jjanes i tried to update the password of postgres to make sure it is still `postgres` i can create a table when i access `psql postgres` and start the regular django with `python manage.py runserver` but when i check django and the db with `docker-compose logs` there seem to be an issue connecting the db with docker compose

Comment: @jjanes found the issue and posted the answer below, `docker volume` was the problem

Answer (score 0):

to anybody ever going through the same problem

all you have to do is `docker-compose down --volumes`

then

`docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate`

:)